# div click event not being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Click events for the child nodes the parent are not fired when html is append to the div but event is fired when content is static on `document.ready`. Is there something im doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
runAPISearch(); //Make httpRquest to movieDBAPi
$('.card').click(function(e) {
console.log("remove div"); //CLICK EVENT NOT FIRED
});

$('.cardImg').click(function(e) {
    console.log("clicked Img"); //not fired either.
});

});
```

**functions**

```
function parseData(data){
var i=0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var template = $("#template").html();
    var prependTemplate = template.replace("{{cardId}}", i).replace("{{imgSrc}}", poster_path);
    console.log(prependTemplate);
    $(".container").prepend(prependTemplate);
    }
}//ParseData ends
```

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div id="{{cardId}}" class="card">
<img class="cardImg" src="{{imgSrc}}"> 
    </div>
</script>
<div class="container">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the answer on this question:
[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

You will need to bind the event to a static element and delegate your dynamic element:

```
$('container').on('click','div.card',function(){
    //your function
});
```

Same for the other dynamic element

Answer (score 0):

By the time the http response comes back your functions have already been called because your http request is asynchronous. Try using jquery on function like so.

```
$("body").on( "click", ".card", function() {
  console.log("remove div");
});

$("body").on( "click", ".cardImg", function() {
  console.log("clicked Img");
});
```